# How to defragment SYSTEM?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

I was unable to defragment  **SYSTEM** in Windows7 which is fragmented by 5% as shown in the figure below:
[image]
On selecting **SYSTEM** first and then clicking on **Defragment Disk** option doesn't defragment SYSTEM to 0%
So, can anyone tell some ways by which i can defragment it to 0%

Comment: You don't need to. Leave it alone.

Comment: More specifically, there may be files that are specifically not movable, and this can affect the defragmentability of a volume. In general, if a volume's fragmentation level is low, or your use of the volume is low, you can ignore it. I generally defragged only if I was noticing significant performance hits, and then only if the fragmentation level was over about 30%.

Comment: But I noticed that if defragmentation is not performed for some weeks then my laptop starts giving booting error as "**Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and  press a key_**" ; so that's why i want to defragment my laptop completely to 0%

Comment: @Suresh this sounds like a drive error.  I would run chkdsk.  Fragmentation should not affect a computer's ability to boot.

Comment: @Keltari but when i perform chkdsk , the booting error still exists ; it only goes away only when i do defragmentation in my laptop

Comment: That sounds like a corrupt pagefile. Can you move your pagefile to a different disk?

Comment: @spikey_richie Is it safe to move pagefile location? Will it solve the issue??